# Throughout this and last year(s)

Tags: grammatical-number

"Throughout this and last year" sounds more correct, but saying "this and last" implies two, leading me to believe "years" could be right.

[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/443242/which-is-grammatically-correct-first-and-last-name-or-first-and-last-names) is kind of similar, but the most conclusive answer given there is "both work," so I don't have a real answer yet.

**Side note, I'm actually using the word "semester(s)," just figured using "years" is a little more generic so people looking for the same thing in the future can find this easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is elliptical, and the missing *year* is assumed to exist:

> Throughout this [year] and last year.

A variation would be:

> Throughout this year and the last.

It's the same principle as:

> I'm eating an apple and [an] orange.

---

If you want to make it explicitly clear, then use the full version or a different construction:

> Throughout this year and last year.
>   Throughout the past two years.